# Two homeomorphic non-diffeomorphic complex manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Does there exist a closed topological manifold supporting two non-diffeomorphic smooth structures both of which admit a compatible complex structure? Also the same question, but for symplectic structure.

Comment: This is a well-known problem, which has been solved by Donaldson in the early 80's. See for instance the book *Compact complex surfaces* by Barth, Hulek, Peters, Van de Ven, ch. XI, §5: "Infinitely many homeomorphic surfaces which are not diffeomorphic".

Comment: It would be interesting to have examples of complex dimension greater than two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there are.   There exists infinitely many  proper elliptic surfaces  that are homeomorphic and no two are diffeomorphic.  Each of them carries a Kähler structure. For details see Corollary 3.3.23 of [this book](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/swnotes.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Google tells me that there are these [Horikawa surfaces](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178225460) (I don't know what they are) which posses infinitely many differentiable structures. The fact that the author says *the* Horikawa surface makes me think any such complex surfaces $X,Y$ have the same underlying $X_{top}=Y_{top}$, but the underlying $X_{diff}$, $Y_{diff}$ are possibly non-diffeomorphic.

It also happens for [K3 surfaces](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214448082) by classical work by Donaldson: on *the* (topological) K3 surface there are non-diffeomorphic differentiable structures. I guess they each underlie (a fortiori non biholomorphic) complex structures... [Edit: **no, they don't**: see comment by misha below. So this paragraph is *not* an answer to the question]

I haven't read any of the articles I've cited though. Also I don't know the overlaps with the answer by Liviu Nicolaescu above.

Comment: I do not think that K3 example is correct. By classification of complex surfaces, we know that a complex surface whose underlying topological manifold is a topological K3 has to be a K3 surface; the underlying smooth manifolds of any two K3 surfaces are diffeomorphic. Therefore, exotic smooth structures on topological K3 can not be compatible with complex structure

Comment: @misha: I see, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @misha: oh well, so what about the Hirokawa surfaces? If the exotic ones are non-complex then maybe I'll delete my answer.

Comment: about Horikawa surfaces I am not so sure.

Comment: Horikawa surfaces are of general type as far as I can remember. In particular they are not elliptic.